# Press Enter after I scanned a CodeBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, barcode-scanner

I'm looking the way to press Enter after I finish writing in a input, I'm scanning codebars in my input but after the code is insert it in the input I want to automatic press enter and call my function. This is my code for my input:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_Componente, "Id_Componente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Id_Componente" name="Id_Componente" autofocus="autofocus" onkeypress="FunctionP(event)" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_Componente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

But its only work when I press Enter in the Keyboard, and I want to do something the after I scanned the code bar automatic call my function: FunctionP(event).  Sorry for my English.

Comment: You could probably use the input event and a debounce, however, i'd suggest looking at the docs for your scanner, the ones i've worked with in the past can be configured to cause an enter keypress after input.

Comment: A number of scanners are usually configurable to optionally append a terminating character (usually CR) after a scan.  Might be easier than a software solution

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot read a `\r` (Carriage Return) or `\n` (New Line) from your scanner, you could conditionally perform actions when enough characters have been entered in the field. For example if your Barcode has 32 characters:

```
$("#Id_Componente").keyup(function(e){
  if($(this).val().length == 32){
    // Do something
  }
});
```

This will fail if you have variable lengths. If this is the case, you could look for a specific character as a terminator.